# How to check table for new content, and then update browser tab title?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a way to flash a browser tab when a new message appears in a table. I have the flashing of the tab part working, my only problem is that I can't seem to get it to flash when a message is received (which is the whole point of my exercise :) )

The `newMessage()` function is working fine, I just can't seem to get the `notification()` function to work.

My code is as follows:

```
function newMessage() 
     {
      var oldTitle = "Your Page";
      var msg = "New Message";

      var timeout = setInterval(function() 
      { 
        document.title = document.title == msg ? '' : msg;
      }, 1000);

      window.onmousemove = function() {
          clearInterval(timeout);
          document.title = oldTitle;
          window.onmousemove = null;
      };
     }

function notification()
     {
       var index = 2;

       var content = document.getElementById('refreshMessages').childNodes[index];

        var content = document.getElementById('refreshMessages').getElementByTagName("tr")[1];

        var knownContent = content.toString();

        updater.start();

        updater2.start();

        var newContent = document.getElementById('refreshMessages').childNodes[index];

        var newContent = document.getElementById('refreshMessages').getElementByTagName("tr")[1];

        if(knownContent != newContent.toString())
        {
           newMessage();
           knownContent = newContent;
        }
        else if(knownContent = newContent.toString())
          {
            alert("No need to flash title.");
          }
     }
     notification();
```

In the `notification()` function, I am trying to call the `newMessage()` function by comparing the strings at the appropiate cell in the table.

I put the `alert()` into the else if just to see if it would be called, but it does not happen. `update.start()` and `update2.start()` are carried out however, as I can see the messages appearing in the table.

I would be happier to use JavaScript but I am open to jQuery also.

My JavaScript is very very rusty so excuse me if I have made any silly mistakes!

Thanks,

Chuck

Comment: I can't tell what the problem is without seeing the html, but you are calling `.toString()` on an html element which is a little peculiar and you have a double declaration of `newContent` and `content` which means the first one is basically ignored... what is supposed to be happening here?

Comment: Guessing the code should work(even with the weirdness pointed by ckozl) and your code is in the head section the problem is that the code is executed before the DOM tree is ready and all your `document.getElementById` return `null`, trying to call a method on null raises an error. Try to change your call `notification();` to `window.onload = function(){ notification(); };`.

Comment: I believe modern day browsers queue up/pause setInterval when the tab is not focused. [MDN setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout)

Comment: @Prusse Ah thanks for that, I spent an hour and a half this morning trying to figure out why FireBug was telling me that the table was null, I must have removed `window.onload` somewhere along the line! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several mistakes in function notification(), see my comments:

```
function notification()
{
    var index = 2;

    //Why are you assigning value to "content" for twice?
    var content = document.getElementById('refreshMessages').childNodes[index];
    /*
    * function getElementByTagName is undefined, should be getElementsByTagName, 
    *  's' is missing. And [1] means the second one not the first one, make sure
    *  that's exactly what you want.
    */
    var content = document.getElementById('refreshMessages').getElementByTagName("tr")[1];

    /*
    * content is a tr dom object, content.toString() is something like "[object]".
    * If you want to get content inside a cell, you should use cell.innerHTML.
    * e.g. A table: 
    * <table id="refreshMessages">
    *     <tr><td>Hello world</td></tr>
    * </table>
    * var table = document.getElementById('refreshMessages');
    * var firstTr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0];
    * var firstTd = firstTr.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    * alert(firstTd.innerHTML);      //alerts "Hello world"
    */
    var knownContent = content.toString();

    //I doubt these functions really get invoked cuz there's javascript error above.
    updater.start();

    updater2.start();

    //assigning twice, "getElementByTagName" is missing "s"
    var newContent = document.getElementById('refreshMessages').childNodes[index];
    var newContent = document.getElementById('refreshMessages').getElementByTagName("tr")[1];

    //Remove toString(), use innerHTML i metioned above.
    if(knownContent != newContent.toString())
    {
       newMessage();
       knownContent = newContent;
    }
    //You miss an "=" here, to judge a equals b, you should use "=="
    else if(knownContent = newContent.toString())
    {
        alert("No need to flash title.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank's a million for the help, and apologies for my stupid mistakes, as I said, JavaScript is not my usual area!

Comment: @chuckliddell0 You are welcome. And You don't have to apology for that. Everyone makes mistakes. :)